# Case class causes java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, scala

I have the following `case class`:

```
case class Page(url: String) {
  var content: String = new URL(url).getContent().toString;
}
```

It is instantiated with a url and it is using `java.net.URL` to get the content of the page corresponding to the given url and place it in a field.

The application containing this code is throwing `[RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError]` and I feel that it is coming from here.

Is the code not correct?

Comment: How do you know that it comes from this code? It seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

This part of the code seems fine, see `Scala 2.11.7 REPL`:

```
scala> case class Page(url: String) {
 |   var content: String = new URL(url).getContent().toString;
 | }
 defined class Page


 scala> Page("http://www.google.de")
 res5: Page = Page(http://www.google.de)
```